# AOSP Build. Always Landscape Display

Tags: android, android-source

I'm building from AOSP source code. I have a specific requirement where I need my phone to start in landscape mode, which includes Boot Logo, Animation (Well these can be done by rotating the animation frames). I would want to restrict the device to display only in landscape mode. I have used rotation lock app but I want to have it as part of the OS so the "Android is starting" boot message also will be displayed in Landscape. Where can I make the required changes in the source code? Your inputs are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user rotation in Android. But it only take efferts after the Android boot completed.

If you want to rotate the screen of boot logo, and boot animation, you should rotate the display in low level. There are some place to define the rotation in the display driver and bootloader.

I don't know the exact code place. You may ask you vendor whether the display rotation can be configured. I know that MediaTek provided the configuration to rotate the display.